# Why I fetch wrong result in TensorFlowInferenceInterface in this demo?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

Here is program that make protocol buffer.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import tensorflow as tf

session = tf.Session()

matrix1 = tf.constant([[1., 3.]], name='input1')
matrix2 = tf.constant([[2., 2.]], name='input2')
mat_add = tf.add(matrix1, matrix2, name='output1')
mat_sub = tf.subtract(matrix1, matrix2, name='output2')

session.run(mat_add)
session.run(mat_sub)


tf.train.write_graph(session.graph.as_graph_def(), "./models/", "simple.pb", as_text=False)

session.close()
```

And here is the main part of the java code which interfaces with the TensorFlowInferenceInterface.

```
inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(getAssets(),MODEL_FILE);

input1[0] = (float) 5.0; input1[1] = (float) 6.0;
input2[0] = (float) 2.0; input2[1] = (float) 3.0;


inferenceInterface.feed("input1", input1, new long[]{1,2});
inferenceInterface.feed("input2", input2, new long[]{1,2});

inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"output1","output2"});

inferenceInterface.fetch("output1", output1);
inferenceInterface.fetch("output2", output2);


for(float f : output1)
    Log.i(TAG, "output1: " + f);
for(float f : output2)
    Log.i(TAG, "output2: " + f);
```

And this is [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUOPO.png)

The add result always be correct, but the substract result always be [1.0,1.0], and this is why I can't figure out, the operation of add and subtract are almost the same while the subtraction always wrong and be a
fix value.
Any opinions will be helpful! Please tell me the reason.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using? I can't seem to reproduce your problem in newer versions like 1.4, 1.5, or 1.6. Does using a newer version help?

Also, that said, your graph is defined with inputs as constants, which means graph optimizations may kick in (like constant folding). If you really want to "feed" the inputs, then define them using `tf.placeholder` instead of `tf.constant` in your graph to see if that helps.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am using Tensorflow 1.2 , and the results become correct when I use `tf.placeholder` instead of `tf.constant`. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks ash! The problem has been solved by changing the code

```
matrix1 = tf.constant([[1., 3.]], name='input1')
matrix2 = tf.constant([[2., 2.]], name='input2')
```

to

```
matrix1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1,2), name='input1')
matrix2 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1,2), name='input2')
```